# wsfed authentication in webapp-webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, ws-federation

The issue I am facing is to get webApi authenticated with bearer token received from webapp authentication.

1. Created web app, Angular template of .net core 2.1. Aded WsFed authentication to it. https://demoapp (dummy name)
2. Created Web Api app. Added wsfed authentication to it. https://demoapp-api (dummy name)
   Now target is to authenticate web app, use token from there to make calls to api, and get data.
3. In WebApp, in OnTicketReceived WsFederationEvent, acquiring token using AcquireTokenAsync(AppId, credential);
   Doing this because, we receive SAML token from WsFed. 
   Here tried with AppId of WebAPI, and also of WebApp. Both tokens do not work.
4. Passing this token as Bearer token in header to API.
5. When hitting API, facing redirection for authentication.
6. Ideally, when sending token, it should be allowed, right ?

I have added permissions of WebAPI on WebAPP in Azure portal, and also vice-versa.
Acquiring token using AppSecret.

Am I missing something here ? Or I am trying to achieve something which is not possible with WsFed ?
Can anyone please help with this webapp-webapi-wsfed scenario ?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for using WS-Fed? Would using Open Id Connect and OAuth work? There are plenty of samples for those so it might be easier for you.

Comment: @juunas I need to have both OpenId and WsFed. With openId, I am able to get it working. But need to add support for WsFed too, as we have some clients having ADFS box, and they need to authenticate with that.

Comment: That's a good reason :)